# How to set firstday of the week in oracle jet datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, oracle-jet

I am not able to set first day of the week in oracle jet datepicker while its simple to set in jquery ui

Thanks.

Comment: can you please add your code here or create a jsfiddle so that it's easier to debug your problem.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would also be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

its more of a Javascript question, you can get the first day of week (I am assuming week starts with sunday)

```
let currDate = new Date; // get current date
let first = currDate.getDate() - currDate.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
let firstday = new Date(currDate.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
console.log(firstday);
```

Now you can use this variable firstday as value in oj-date-picker element